# Determine whether $S = \{(1, 0, -1), (2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> How to check if $S = \{(1, 0, -1), (2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ or not?

Comment: i haven't tried cause i don't know how to do it

Comment: See the hint below, but the material you're studying from should cover some basic properties...?

Comment: i just want to know the conditions which a set needs to fulfill in order to span r3

Comment: Either stick to the definition, or use properties if you have seen those / are allowed to use those. I added a bit below.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Yousuf. You are more likely to get some help if you include your own work (and doubts) in your questions.

Comment: 1. do you know what it means that a set of vectors spans $\mathbb{R^3}$? 2. do you know a set of vectors that spans $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the given vectors span $\mathbb{R^3}$ if any vector from $\mathbb{R^3}$ can be written as a linear combination of the three given vectors. You can check this but there are easier alternatives.

**Hint**

Three vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ span $\mathbb{R^3}$ if they are *linearly independent*. Can you check that?

---

Addition after comments; example to check linear independence:

- $(1,-2)$ and $(-3,6)$ are not linearly independent in $\mathbb{R^2}$ because you can make a linear combination $k_1(1,-2)+k_2(-3,6) = (0,0)$ without having to take $k_1=k_2=0$, take for example $k_1=3$ and $k_2=1$;
- $(1,-2)$ and $(1,1)$ *are* linearly independent in $\mathbb{R^2}$ because the only way to get $k_1(1,-2)+k_2(1,1) = (0,0)$ is to take $k_1=k_2=0$ (solve the system te check this).

Comment: yes if the scalars like k1, k2, k3 are o then they are independent

Comment: @YousufKhan You should try to be a bit more careful with phrasing. The vectors are linearly independent if **the only way** to form the zero vector as a linear combination of the given vectors, is by taking all the scalars $0$. They are indeed linearly independent.

Comment: i am not able to understand it can you please explain it in simple english

Comment: if i have to check the question i stated above i need to find if it's linearly independant or dependant if it's linearly independent then it spans r3

Comment: It's better to include your (detailed) question(s) _in the question_, rather than in comments; so perhaps you should edit your question if it's still not clear. Other people can add answers or I can update mine, if you have further questions.

Comment: i only want to ask a thing that we can check it by putting all the vectors a, b, c=0

Comment: @YousufKhan Please don't be impatient and read the other comments. Your question isn't clear; what don't you understand about my first comment? That explains how you can check for linear independence (it's not "putting the vectors 0", it's verifying if you can make the zero vector without having to take all the scalars $0$ - if not: the vectors are linearly independent).

Comment: sir i am also a bit confused because i haven't took the lecture how can i  it's verifying if you can make the zero vector without having to take all the scalars 00 - do it??

Comment: i want to know that how can u check that a vector is linearly independent or dependent

Comment: I've added a simple example to my answer to illustrate the approach. Depending on what you have seen about linear (in)dependence, there are other ways to check it as well.

Comment: thnks very mush